# Changing time -1 hour

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that passes a timestamp string in the format of `2014-10-31T11:28:02+00:00` into another variable. How can I minus one hour from this?

For example:

`$currDate = $userDate - strtotime('-1 hour');`

Where `$userDate` contains `2014-10-31T11:28:02+00:00`.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching here before asking?

Comment: http://php.net/datetime - The DateTime class is a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` is for converting a timestamp to the time in seconds similar to the output that `time()` gives you.

That said, the code `strtotime("-1 hour")` will not work.

What you could do however is convert the user timestamp to the time in seconds and then subtract one hour from this, like so

```
$currDate = strtotime($userDate) - 3600; // 1 hour has 3600 seconds
```

And then convert `$currDate` back to a timestamp, by doing something like this

```
$finalDate = date("YYYY-mm-dd HH:ss", $currDate); // adjust the format to your needs
```

The way formatting using `date()` works can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Just a note: For a list of all the available format characters for `date()`, refer to the [official PHP manual documentation](http://php.net/date).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$str = '2014-10-31T11:28:02+00:00';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $str);
$dt->modify("-1 hours");
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
$currDate = strtotime($userDate) - 3600;
```

If you want to keep the format of `$userDate` then do this:

```
$newUserDate = date("c", strtotime($userDate) - 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`DateTime`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

- Create `DateTime` object from your desired date format
- Subtract the hour
- Echo the new date in your desired format

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TG:i:sP', '2014-10-31T11:28:02+00:00');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TG:i:sP');
```

https://eval.in/214784

Comment: The date is in  ISO 8601 format, so you don't need to explicitly specify the format, as PHP's date parser recognizes it already. You could simply write: `$date = new DateTime($userDate);`. For formatting, you could use [`$date->format('c');`](http://php.net/date).

Comment: You can use only the `c` format to output an ISO 8601 date. Also since the input date is an ISO 8601 date there is no need to format the input, you ca do straight `new DateTime('2014-10-31T11:28:02+00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in date format .There must be space between date and timestamp. Following works pefectly.

```
$userDate='2014-10-31 T11:28:02+00:00';
echo $currDate = $d= date('d-m-Y',strtotime($userDate. " -1 hour"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($userDate .'-1 hour'));
```

try this........... in "Y-m-d" you add your format like as "y-m-d H:i:s"